# Automatically print Excel from Windows Service

Tags: c#, excel, windows-services, office-interop

We have a Windows Service containing a FileSystemWatcher. This watcher picks up new file creations & generates an Excel document. The Excel document is then sent to a printer automatically using the Excel Interop.

All the setup around Excel Automation has been performed (creating the Desktop directory in `C:\Windows\SysWOW64\config\systemprofile`, giving local activation rights to the service account on the Microsoft Excel Application).

The printing works for a few days, but then all of a sudden, seemingly at random, the Excel Interop fails to print. The service gets stuck & does not continue processing. No exceptions occur, the service just stops & appears to hang. The below line of code is where this occurs:

```
ws.PrintOutEx(Type.Missing, Type.Missing, Type.Missing, Type.Missing, printerName, Type.Missing, Type.Missing, Type.Missing);
```

`ws` above is an instance of `Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Worksheet`

Once this happens, no intervention seems to solve it. We've tried stopping the service (using `taskkill`, as it becomes unresponsive), killing the EXCEL.exe process that's running & starting it back up. We've also tried a reboot of the server (running Windows Server 2008). Every time a new file is loaded, the service gets stuck on this line. The only way to resolve it, is by uninstalling & reinstalling Excel.

Does anyone have an inkling as to what might be the cause of this & how it may be resolved? Even alternative suggestions for reading a file & sending an Excel document to a printer automatically would be welcome.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Microsoft does not currently recommend, and does not support, Automation of Microsoft Office applications from any unattended, non-interactive client application or component (including ASP, ASP.NET, DCOM, and NT Services), because Office may exhibit unstable behavior and/or deadlock when Office is run in this environment.**

If you are building a solution that runs in a server-side context, you should try to use components that have been made safe for unattended execution. Or, you should try to find alternatives that allow at least part of the code to run client-side. If you use an Office application from a server-side solution, the application will lack many of the necessary capabilities to run successfully. Additionally, you will be taking risks with the stability of your overall solution. Read more about that in the [Considerations for server-side Automation of Office](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/257757) article.

As a workaround you may consider using the Open XML SDK, see [Welcome to the Open XML SDK 2.5 for Office](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/bb448854.aspx). Or just use third-party components designed for the server-side execution.

Comment: Thank you for the quick response! OK, so if it shouldn't be done with unattended, non-interactive clients, could something like a console application be used to act as the monitor? The reason we're using the Interop is that the Excel template used has a vertically rotated cell, which none of the 3rd party libraries seem to be able to produce on the printouts.